# Firebase When deploying Cloud Function with Typesense Type 'T' does not satisfy the constraint 'DocumentSchema'

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase, typesense

I am having a problem when deploying my typesense cloud functions. I have installed the typesense npm package in my project.
I have the following for my cloud function, updateUserInfoInTypesense:

```
export const updateUserInfoInTypesense = functions
      .region("us-central1")
      .firestore
      .document("users/{userId}")
      .onUpdate(async (change) => {

        const isPro = await isAtlistedPro(change.before.id);
        const isRegular = await isRegularUser(change.before.id);

        if (isRegular) {
          const previousDocument = change.before.data() as UserInfo;
          const document = change.after.data() as UserInfo;

          if (!compareUserInfo(previousDocument, document)) {
            return indexNormalUser(previousDocument, document).catch((error) => {
              functions.logger.log(
                  "error in updateUserInfoInTypesense catch",
                  error
              );
            });
          } else {
            return {success: true, exit: 5};
          }
        
        
        } else if (isPro) {
          const previousDocument = change.before.data() as ProUserInfo;
          const document = change.after.data() as ProUserInfo;

          if (!compareProUserInfo(previousDocument, document)) {
            return indexProWithEvents(previousDocument, document).catch((error) => {
              functions.logger.log(
                  "error in updateUserInfoInTypesense catch",
                  error
              );
            });
          } else {
            return {success: true, exit: 5};
          }
        } else {
          return {success: false, exit: 8};
        }
        
      });
```

When I go to deploy this, I get the following errors:

```
node_modules/typesense/lib/Typesense/Documents.d.ts:113:92 - error TS2344: Type 'T' does not satisfy the constraint 'DocumentSchema'.

113     search(searchParameters: SearchParams, options: SearchOptions): Promise<SearchResponse<T>>;
                                                                                               ~

  node_modules/typesense/lib/Typesense/Documents.d.ts:112:38
    112 export interface SearchableDocuments<T> {
                                             ~
    This type parameter might need an `extends DocumentSchema` constraint.

node_modules/typesense/lib/Typesense/MultiSearch.d.ts:11:29 - error TS2344: Type 'T' does not satisfy the constraint 'DocumentSchema'.

11     results: SearchResponse<T>[];
                               ~

  node_modules/typesense/lib/Typesense/MultiSearch.d.ts:10:38
    10 export interface MultiSearchResponse<T> {
                                            ~
    This type parameter might need an `extends DocumentSchema` constraint.

node_modules/typesense/lib/Typesense/SearchOnlyDocuments.d.ts:12:131 - error TS2344: Type 'T' does not satisfy the constraint 'DocumentSchema'.

12     search(searchParameters: SearchParams, { cacheSearchResultsForSeconds, abortSignal }?: SearchOptions): Promise<SearchResponse<T>>;
                                                                                                                                     ~

  node_modules/typesense/lib/Typesense/SearchOnlyDocuments.d.ts:5:42
    5 export declare class SearchOnlyDocuments<T> implements SearchableDocuments<T> {
                                               ~
    This type parameter might need an `extends DocumentSchema` constraint.


Found 3 errors in 3 files.

Errors  Files
     1  node_modules/typesense/lib/Typesense/Documents.d.ts:113
     1  node_modules/typesense/lib/Typesense/MultiSearch.d.ts:11
     1  node_modules/typesense/lib/Typesense/SearchOnlyDocuments.d.ts:12
```

These all seem to be problems in the libraries within Typesense and I have no errors pointing back to my original code. Has anyone seen this? I am a bit confused as to what I am doing wrong.

Here is my package.json, for your reference:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint --ext .ts .",
    "build": "tsc",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "test": "mocha --reporter spec --timeout 10000",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "14"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.19.4",
    "@firebase/app-compat": "^0.1.28",
    "@types/rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "chai": "^4.3.4",
    "csv-parse": "^5.2.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^9.8.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.16.0",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "mocha": "^9.1.3",
    "puppeteer": "^10.4.0",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4",
    "typesense": "^1.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.33.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.33.0",
    "eslint": "^7.6.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.0",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: This could potentially be due to a mismatch in Typescript versions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57673603/123545

Comment: Much thanks! The problem was the mismatch in global and local versions of Typescript.