# Error in Typesense Node Modules When using Typesense with Ionic 4

Tags: typescript, ionic4, angular7, typesense

I am getting the following output when running ionic serve in my project directory:

```
ERROR in node_modules/typesense/lib/Typesense/Documents.d.ts(2,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[ng] node_modules/typesense/lib/Typesense/Documents.d.ts(2,33): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[ng] node_modules/typesense/lib/Typesense/SearchOnlyDocuments.d.ts(4,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[ng] node_modules/typesense/lib/Typesense/SearchOnlyDocuments.d.ts(4,87): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[ng]
```

I recognized that this error was very similar to this question I asked recently:
[Firebase When deploying Cloud Function with Typesense Type 'T' does not satisfy the constraint 'DocumentSchema'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74020836/firebase-when-deploying-cloud-function-with-typesense-type-t-does-not-satisfy)

In that post the problem turned out to be that I was using different global and local versions of typescript. It was the case, in this project that the versions were off, so I fixed it. The following details my versions:

```
npm ls typescript -g
/usr/local/lib
└── typescript@3.2.4 

npm ls typescript
myproject@0.0.1 /home/me/myproject
├─┬ @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.13.9
│ └─┬ @angular-devkit/build-optimizer@0.13.9
│   └── typescript@3.2.4 
├─┬ @angular/cli@7.3.9
│ └─┬ @schematics/angular@7.3.9
│   └── typescript@3.2.4 
├─┬ @ionic/angular-toolkit@1.4.1
│ └── typescript@3.2.4  deduped
└── typescript@3.2.4
```

For some reason this project wants to pull different typescript versions for different dependencies, however, as you can see above, I managed to get them all on the same version of typescript.

Below is my package.json. This all runs smoothly when doing npm install, with no errors:

```
{
  "name": "myproject",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "7.2.16",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.3.7",
    "@angular/common": "7.2.16",
    "@angular/core": "7.2.16",
    "@angular/fire": "^5.2.1",
    "@angular/forms": "7.2.16",
    "@angular/material": "^7.3.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "7.2.16",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "7.2.16",
    "@angular/router": "7.2.16",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.19.4",
    "@ctrl/ngx-emoji-mart": "^0.17.0",
    "@firebase/testing": "^0.20.11",
    "@google-cloud/firestore": "^3.8.6",
    "@ionic-native/badge": "^5.35.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-chooser": "^5.9.0",
    "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^5.13.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^4.6.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.37.5",
    "angular-calendar": "^0.27.14",
    "angular-material-expansion-panel": "^0.7.2",
    "cordova-browser": "5.0.4",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "4.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.1.1",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "date-fns": "^1.30.1",
    "dateformat": "^5.0.2",
    "firebase": "^6.2.4",
    "ini": "^2.0.0",
    "ionic2-calendar": "^0.5.2",
    "ng-bootstrap": "^1.6.3",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.2",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.2",
    "tslib": "^2.3.1",
    "typesense": "^1.4.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.29"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "^0.1201.3",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.13.7",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "~7.3.7",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "~7.3.7",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.3.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "7.2.16",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "7.2.16",
    "@angular/language-service": "7.2.16",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "~1.4.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~12.0.0",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "cordova-plugin-badge": "^0.8.8",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~5.17.0",
    "typescript": "3.2.4"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-geolocation": {},
      "cordova-plugin-badge": {}
    },
    "config": {
      "ionic_copy": "./config/copy.config.js"
    },
    "platforms": [
      "browser"
    ]
  }
}
```

Please let me know what else I can do to resolve this.

If the answer is to make this:

```
myproject@0.0.1 /home/me/myproject
├─┬ @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.13.9
│ └─┬ @angular-devkit/build-optimizer@0.13.9
│   └── typescript@3.2.4 
├─┬ @angular/cli@7.3.9
│ └─┬ @schematics/angular@7.3.9
│   └── typescript@3.2.4 
├─┬ @ionic/angular-toolkit@1.4.1
│ └── typescript@3.2.4  deduped
└── typescript@3.2.4
```

look like this:

```
myproject@0.0.1 /home/me/myproject
└── typescript@3.2.4
```

Please advise me on how to do that.

It is also worth noting that in that previous question I had resolved global and local versions to be typescript@4.4.4 but here I needed typescript@3.2.4 to work with my ionic and angular versions.

Comment: To update: I ran npm dedupe, but this did not help the error.

Comment: I ended up upgrading to NodeJS 14 and it solved this problem. Of course I had to update my entire project with compatible packages (Angular, Ionic, etc.) which took a while.