# Imports, Types and Typescript Compilation in Vanilla JS Project

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a very unorthodox setup for my current project. The project consists of a django application with multiple "apps" or folders that try to containerize the logic of different sections of the website. I wanted to introduce Typescript into the project, since I love the benefits of typesafety.

However, since this is running purely on Django (no framework running in parallel to the backend, just scripts included in an HTML script tag), what I opted in to do was to just create Typescript files, transpile them and then use the resulting JS files in the HTML script tags required. Each app or folder has a "static" folder, with two subfolders inside: "ts" and "js". Beside those two folders, there is a `tsconfig.json` with the following config

```json
{
    "extends": "../../../tsconfig.json", // Path to global tsconfig.json
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "js", // Where the transpiled Javascript files go
        "rootDir": "ts", // Where the Typescript files are
    },
}
```

This helps the compiler know that I want the files in the `ts` folder to be put in the `js` folder. Django then simply picks up the resulting JS files and uses them.

As you can see, the config uses a parent configuration with the same name, that contains the following:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "ES2015",                     // Include imports/exports in the transpiled Javascript
        "moduleResolution": "node",             // Use the locally installed Node modules 
        "lib": [
            "es2019",
            "dom",
            "DOM.Iterable",
            "es2017"
        ],
        "sourceMap": true,                      // Generates a map file that allows us to see the "non-minified" code when debugging
        "noUnusedParameters": true,             // Warns when a function parameter is not used
        "noImplicitReturns": true,              // Enforce always adding types to function inputs
        "removeComments": true,                 // Remove comments from the transpiled JS file
        "strict": true,                         // Enable all strict type checking options


        // Include the globally installed modules
        // (Check where your global modules are installed with: npm root -g)
        // NOTE: The first type root is used by the node_opus container. The
        // rest you can use them to point to your locally installed global
        // modules.  
        "typeRoots": [
            "/home/node/opus/nodejs/node_modules/@types",
            "./nodejs/node_modules/@types"
        ],

        // Specify "types": [] to disable automatic inclusion of @types packages.
        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47303252
        "types": ["jquery"]
    },

    // Exclude the "node_modules" folder from the transpilation process
    "exclude": [ "node_modules" ]
}
```

Everything good up to here. Scripts compile into JS files and files that are next to each other can be imported really easily with proper linting support:

```js
import { APIError } from "./types/common.js";
```

However, one of the errors that I have found is that when I try to reference a Typescript file found in a different app, like in the following example

```js
import { OpusProgressBar } from "../../../../static/app_core/js/components/progressBar.js";
```

I get the following error: `Could not find a declaration file for module "X". "X" implicitly has an "any" type`. This is a pretty big deal breaker for me, since this removes type annotations from my imports, which was the reason I introduced Typescript in the first place.

I tried looking around at how to fix this, and while trying to do this, discovered a few things:

- When I go to the transpiled Javascript file, that file actually has proper type annotations.
- Some posts mentioned the fact that I need to use a `.d.ts` file to solve the problem. I created a sample `progressBar.d.ts` and included it in the parent `tsconfig.json` file like you can see below. This caused all imports in my files to be automatically fixed. With them getting correct linting support. No idea why this would work

```js
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        ...
    },

    // Exclude the "node_modules" folder from the transpilation process
    "exclude": [ "node_modules" ],
    "include": [ "progressBar.d.ts" ]
}
```

- When the previously mentioned thing worked, I tried compiling, and it failed. It told me that the include setting in my `tsconfig.json` did not include the files that I was trying to compile. So I added an entry for my scripts in the `include` setting like this `[ "progressBar.d.ts", "./app_name/**/ts/*"]`. This made the compilation work again, but my imports broke again
- I have jQuery installed in my npm global modules, and I use the `$` symbol associated with jQuery in multiple scripts for my Django project. Interestingly, for that specific package I do have linting. However, when I fixed my imports, the linting for it just went away

Im sure all of these "symptoms" might sound familiar to someone out there who might be able to help me out. Maybe someone can help me out so that I can have a setup with both correct linting and proper compilation behavior. I just want to code and not have to worry about this tbh. Thank you!

IDE: VSCode

Comment: 1. Unless you have to support 12 year old browsers (I'm talking IE 9 or lower here) setting your output to ES5 is a terrible idea, and it should *probably* be something like `es2020`. 2. the `.d.ts` should be generated during compilation: you shouldn't have to create it and it should go in the same directory as the output JS file. Set `"declaration": true` in your tsconfig. 3. There is a difference between your IDE not being able to find a dep and the actual compiler not being able to do so. Make sure this isn't just a problem with vscode/pycharm/whatever-the-hell-people-use-these-days.

Comment: Good to know. Switched to es2020 and suspected that I needed to generate the declarations. Switched that setting as well. However, no changes still to my linting. But thank you for the suggestions. Edited the post to include my IDE if thats relevant

Comment: Interestingly, the errors were mostly solved by the `declaration: true` setting. The only place where its not working, is when I use external packages (like from NPM or a CDN for example). I manually added the types for that, but its not working as intended. Will look into that.

Comment: Most external packages that have type declarations either include them in the package itself or host them in the DefinitelyTyped repo (`npm install @types/name-of-package`). But not all of them do: it's possible some of your deps don't have type definitions.

Comment: Its interesting, cause what I did was download @formkit/autoanimate as a CDN package, and then I just downloaded the corresponding .d.ts files and put them alongside the package.min.js. Thought this was going to work, but nope.

Comment: Yeah that isn't going to work

Comment: Any suggestions on how to approach this?

Comment: Yeah, install it normally via yarn or npm. It's written in TS and should come with the type declarations. The TS compiler isn't going to be able to understand or check something at compile-time that gets loaded into a page via script tag pointing at a CDN at runtime. Also what do you mean by "put them alongside package.min.js"? If you're loading stuff from a CDN how could you "put .d.ts files alongside" it?

Comment: I think I didnt explain myself correctly, sorry. Currently my project doesn't have support for NPM, so I cannot "install via NPM". Django is not currently equiped to load said packages, as it doesnt have any module bundler. So what I've been doing is download the minified source file of the package that you want to use, and put it into a `vendors` folder. The packages in that folder are then included via a script tag in my HTML. What I did was download the accompanying `.d.ts` file for the package with a local instance of NPM, and put it next to the `.min.js` file that I downloaded

Comment: "Currently my project doesn't have support for NPM, so I cannot 'install via NPM'" not true, if your project exists on a computer you can and should use the package manager. "Django is not currently equiped to load said packages, as it doesnt have any module bundler" so install a module bundler via npm and bundle your client-side code. Look, if your app is mostly jinja templates and the logic happens in the server in Python that's cool, I ain't trying to kink shame. But if your client-side logic is sufficiently complicated that you need TS, then you need to make it a *real* front-end project.

Comment: I'm not saying one approach is right/better, but pick one. The belt-and-suspenders business is going to lead to lots of pain for little to no gain.

Comment: Oh I know that its not the ideal thing to do. I would love to have a react or whathever thing running. But that would mean translating a lot of logic, and a lot of time, and Im just a one man team, with not that much time unfortunately

Comment: Then just don't use Typescript. But if you decide you need it you don't need to use React, or move server-side logic to the client, or anything like that, just install your JS deps through npm (like you do with pip for your server code) and bundle your client-side js for django to serve. It's not that hard to set up, I'm guessing it will take you an afternoon, tops.